# Trying to implement a custom route in umbraco 7.5.3 but the overrided method FindContent does not get fired

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, umbraco, umbraco7, custom-routes

I've trying to retrieve the rendermodel model into my custom hijacked method, but i always get null. The two optional parameters are correct.

This is my custom route :

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
        "umbracoRoute",
        "token-verification/{action}/{userId}/{code}",
        new
        {
            controller = "ExternalLinkOperations",
            action = "",
            userId = UrlParameter.Optional,
            code = UrlParameter.Optional
        },
        new ConfirmEmailRouteHandler(3290)
        );
```

this is the ConfirmEmailRouteHandler class:

```
public class ConfirmEmailRouteHandler: UmbracoVirtualNodeByIdRouteHandler
{
    public ConfirmEmailRouteHandler(int realNodeId) : base(realNodeId)
    {
    }

    protected override IPublishedContent FindContent(RequestContext requestContext, UmbracoContext umbracoContext, IPublishedContent baseContent)
    {
        return base.FindContent(requestContext, umbracoContext, baseContent);
    }
}
```

and this is the the method in the ExternalLinkOperationsController which inherit from rendermodel:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmEmail(RenderModel model, string userId, string code)
{}
```

so Im not getting the model parameter only the two optional parameter, what i could be doing wrong, I also tried to make this

```
 new UmbracoVirtualNodeByIdRouteHandler(3290)
```

instead of

```
new ConfirmEmailRouteHandler(3290),
```

but without success, I'm using umbraco v 7.5.3. Debugging the code in any moment the overrided method FindContent gets fired, only when the constructor.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

I didn't realized the route property is incorrect, i have RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute, and i am supposed to be using RouteTable.Routes.MapUmbracoRoute

answer by Shannon Deminick [here](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7/59312-Umbraco-7-setup-with-custom-route-values#comment-268825)!